# How to connect to Samba on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: login, samba, virtualbox-networking

With Ubuntu 16, connections from Windows 7 to directories shared by Samba work smoothly. After installing Ubuntu 18 and fresh new Samba installation (along with Samba user and pwd), each  attempt to login to Ubuntu (running in a virtual box) ends with "Incorrect password".
The configuration is checked, everything's in place.

Comment: Possibly related to this? https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-beaver-samba-shares.html